# web page is trying to open a site on your intranet

Tags: c#, iis, ssl

I have a web site that work with external Credit Card Processing (cybersource) 
when user want to buy the webpage redirect to cybersource the user fill his details
and click buy, the page redirect to my web site and show this message

*"the current web page is trying to open a site on your intranet do you want to allow this"*

the user need to click yes or no how can i avoid this message to show up?

Thanks

Comment: Check your pages and the redirect URL you send to the gateway. You may have a broken link (or an `img src`) pointing to a local UNC path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought - are you testing this with a server that *is* on your own intranet?  If so then it's a spurious warning that doesn't require any action from you to change.  I don't think that many end-users will be using your site from the same intranet as the production webserver. :-)